# $f(x) \in\Bbb Q[x]$. Prove that if $f(a + b\sqrt c) = 0$, where $a, b \in\Bbb Q$ and $\sqrt c \in\Bbb Q$ then $f(a − b\sqrt c) = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$. Prove that if $f(a + b\sqrt c) = 0$, where $a, b \in\Bbb Q$ and $\sqrt c \not\in \Bbb Q$ then $f(a − b\sqrt c) = 0$.

I don't really have any idea of where to start on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well think about working out $f(a+b\sqrt{c})$ by hand. You will get a lot of terms with powers of $\sqrt c$. Adding up all the odd powers will give $B\sqrt c$ for some $B\in \mathbb{Q}$ and adding up the even powers will give $A$ for some $B\in \mathbb{Q}$. But since $\sqrt{c}\notin\mathbb{Q}$ you must have $A=B=0$. Now when you work out $f(a-b\sqrt{c})$ you must get $A-B\sqrt{c}$.

Comment: Adam Hughes' answer is great, but if you want a Galois-esque proof, consider the following solution: Let $\sigma$ be the non-trivial automorphism in $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{c})/\mathbb{Q})$. Then $0 = \sigma(f(a + b\sqrt{c})) = f(\sigma(a) + b\sigma(c)) = f(a - b\sqrt{c})$, as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $F=\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-c)$. Then the image $\overline{f}(x)\in F$ has as a factor $(x-a-b\sqrt{c})$. But then $f(x)$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial for $a+b\sqrt{c}$ over $\Bbb Q$ which is $(x-a-b\sqrt c)(x-a+b\sqrt c)= x^2 -2ax+(a^2-cb^2)\in\Bbb Q[x]$, which of course has $a-b\sqrt c$ as a root.